# How to estimate of the pressure in the forced Stokes Equation in $L^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: differential-equations, navier-stokes

Let's consider the following system
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
  \begin{split}
    u_t+\nabla P &=& \Delta u+f, \quad &x\in \Omega\times(0,T),\\
    \nabla \cdot u&=& 0, & x\in \Omega\times(0,T),\\
    u&=& 0, & x\in \partial\Omega\times(0,T),\\
    u(x,0)&=& u_0, &x\in \Omega,
   \end{split}
   \right.
\end{equation*}
where $\Omega\subset R^3$ is a bounded smooth domain.

For $p\in[1,\frac32)$, by the Stokes semigroup theory, there is an estimate
\begin{equation*}
  \|u\|_{L^{2p}(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|u_0\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}+C\|f\|_{L^1(\Omega)},\quad t\in(0,T).
\end{equation*}

My question is  "In this case, how to estimate the pressure", namely, "How to obtain the regularity of the pressure $P$  in Stokes equation when $f\in L^1(\Omega)$".